# Show User Accept Rates

Tags: script, questions, users

This simple user script restores the display of [a user's question accept rate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/136951/189912) on questions they ask.

[image: User Accept Rate on Server Fault]

[image: User Accept Rate on Meta]

**Known Issues:**

- New: In Firefox, throws a "no element found" error and fails to display anything.
- New: Users will not see an accept rate if they have been API rate limited by Stack Exchange.
- Can't Fix: The hover text which showed exact question counts has not been reproduced, because there is no easy way to obtain this information via the API.

**Thanks:**

- To [Manishearth](https://stackapps.com/users/10098/manishearth) for fixing a style bug.

**Install:**

Version: 0.4

[Install](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5997591/raw/4a61db173ca7536b84ba139f3c86ed9ae2d44797/acceptrate.user.js) (See [this page](https://stackapps.com/tags/script/info) if you have trouble installing this) | [Source](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5997591)

**Changes:**

- Version 0.4: Fixed a style bug causing the accept rate text to appear improperly.
- Version 0.3: Initial public release.

Comment: Michael, it doesn't appear to be working in Firefox 22.0.

Comment: Does this work in Chrome? I installed it but it doesn't appear to be working.

Comment: @slm It's working just fine for me. Try visiting a page other than _this_ one.

Comment: I did, I visited several pages across several SE sites. I'll take a look to see what's up but I just was checking.

Comment: Doesn't work for me too. Chrome Linux 28.0.1500.95 (Official Build 213514), V8 3.18.5.14

Comment: @GioMac I still have no idea, since it's _still_ working fine for me. Got any errors, or anything?

Comment: nope, nothing on the screen, howto debug? is there any change on the site/api etc?

Comment: @GioMac Hit F12 and look at the console.

Comment: nothing in here - its empty

Comment: Now it works again :)

Comment: @GioMac You probably got [API rate limited](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle). I didn't make any changes.

Comment: Yeap, possibly - I'm heavy user of tabs, got about 50 open tabs :)

Comment: I recently added this to a new machine and it did not work. So I compared with the place where it works and found that the gm_jq_xhr.js seems to be causing the issue. Also any voting (any ajax based actions) also don't work. I don't see any error in the console though. Here is the [diff](http://jsbin.com/suzuvatidu/1). The left is latest source which causes issues and the right is source that I had earlier and works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I've updated this to work with current SE (which was just an edit to include HTTPS instead of HTTP sites) and just tweaked the code a bit to use jQuery functions in place of building elements with text.

[Source](https://gist.github.com/miken32/1903bb2d9242ce01a70b48ae8f4abade/)

[Install](https://gist.github.com/miken32/1903bb2d9242ce01a70b48ae8f4abade/raw/12428aa331cc0946aaa349a53e9617eee1c7b0e5/acceptrate.user.js)