# User accept rate and home site

Tags: script

It displays the user's accept rate in their userbox on questions (updated to work with Firefox lately), and also the site on which they have the most rep (besides the current 
one) and the amount of rep they have there.

Me, without an accept rate (due to few questions):

[image: User with no rate]

Some other guy, with an accept rate:

[image: User has rate]

Known issue: It doesn't nicely format the rep on the other site with "k" or ",".

It is a fork of [User Accept Rate](https://stackapps.com/questions/4226/user-accept-rate) and you should pick this one or that, but not both.  This one makes two API calls per question; that one makes one.

[Get the script on GitHub Gist.](https://gist.github.com/falconkirtaran/2cb459739024c7eb3c14)

- 0.1: Initial version
- 0.2: Fix jQuery dependency strangeness

Comment: This isn't working for me. Does it work on all sites? I'm not seeing a difference here from how it was before.